# Getting error while install mailchimp

Tags: visual-studio, nuget-package, mailchimp-api-v3.0

i have tried to add MailChimp package in my application using NuGet and NuGet Console.

i got the following error.

'MailChimp.Net.V3' already has a dependency defined for 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions'

How to fix the issue. any one have any idea?